# MySQL INSERT a JSON object from PHP with an apostrophe

Tags: php, mysql, json

I receive valid JSON from a Webhook callback, and i'm trying to store the response in MySQL 5.7.

So I created my MySQL table,

```
CREATE TABLE `reports`(
  uuid VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  docCreatedAt INT(20) NOT NULL,
  doc json,
  UNIQUE(uuid),
  INDEX(docCreatedAt)
)
```

And then I try to INSERT the entire response into the DOC (JSON) column.
Some of that data has apostrophes in the data, as well as arrays of content, similar to:

```
{
    "id": "c0a0e245-8d70-46bc-ac7d-7a02017cb849",
    "customer": {
        "id": "07f42e0f-6824-48fd-88ac",
        "firstName": "John",
        "birthDate": null,
        "emails": [
            {
                "id": "6c16f9bb-cb0f-40b3-888d-8ba331cb31ce",
                "email": "test@test.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "6307c973-8151-4eeb-9cc4-9da253573677",
            "productTitle": "This is the product's name"
        }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "orderTags": []
}
```

Currently, my PHP is receiving the data through

```
$body = file_get_contents("php://input");
$bodyDecoded = json_decode($body);
```

And then run an INSERT on my database

```
$exec = "INSERT INTO `reports` (`uuid`, `docCreatedAt`, `doc`) VALUES ('{$uuid}', $docCreatedAt, JSON_OBJECT($json) )";
```

If there are no single-quotes in my data, it will enter, but if there is, it error's out (syntax, or apostrophe) issues. I've tried everything that I know how to do. So I'm hoping to receive some extra feedback on next steps or best solutions to store. I don't need to do many queries on the data, but would still like to query the JSON data too.

Comment: Use a prepared statement with parameters and you won't have any problems with special characters.

Comment: Best way: parametrized queries (prepared statements). Second best way: escaping. Are you using PDO or MySQLi? The syntax is different between them.

Comment: Ahhh Using PDO...